# How to get progress when uploading file VIA XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, filereader, fileapi

I am wondering how to get the progress of a file upload using XMLHTTPRequest. In Firefox the onprogress method does not fire at all, and in chrome it only fires after the file has finished uploading.

```
function fileUpload(file)
{
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onprogress = function(e)
    {
        alert('progress');
    };

    xhr.open('POST', 'post.php', true);

    xhr.send(formData);  // multipart/form-data
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `xhr.upload.onprogress`. In the XMLHttpRequest2 spec XMLHttpRequest have upload attribute.

> The ability to register for progress events. Both for downloads (put
>   listeners on the XMLHttpRequest object itself) and uploads (put
>   listeners on the XMLHttpRequestUpload object, returned by the upload
>   attribute).
>   http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/#differences