# how add uploading progress bar in express

Tags: upload, progress-bar, express

am using jquery_form to upload file to express server,it works.but without progress bar.so please help add the progress bar.and am sure a lot of people also need this.

so here is the code

client side:

```
$('#uploadvideoform').ajaxSubmit({
            error:function(xhr){
                alert(xhr);
            },
            success:function(response){
                var videopath = response.path;
                var videoview  = "<video width='320' height='240' controls='controls'>";
                    videoview += "<source src="+videopath+" type='video/mp4' />";
                    videoview += "Your browser does not support the video tag.";
                    videoview += "</video>";
                $('#view_product_video_content').append(videoview);
            },
        })

    return false;
```

server side:

```
exports.upload = function(req, res){
 var serverPath = 'Temp\\' + req.files.productvideo.name;

 // console.log('req.files.productvideo.path '+req.files.productvideo.path)
 // console.log('F:\\unit2\\'+serverPath);
 require('fs').rename(
  req.files.productvideo.path,
  'F:\\unit2\\'+serverPath,
  function(error){
    if(error){
      console.log(error)
      return;
    }

    res.send({
      path:serverPath,
    });

  });
```

};

Answer (score 0):

You could use a normal XMLHttpRequest. It is supported by all modern browsers, except the current [IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2). Have a look at the examples:

- [HTML5Rocks: New Tricks in XMLHTTPREQUEST2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/)
- [SO: How to get progress from XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest)
- [SO: How to get progress when uploading file VIA XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409954/how-to-get-progress-when-uploading-file-via-xmlhttprequest)
- [SO: XmlHttpRequest onprogress interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495625/xmlhttprequest-onprogress-interval)